# Linux move files from dir to dir by name mask

Tags: linux, file, mv

I am trying to move all files with names starts with `SML` from directory to another.
Tried with

`find /var/.../Images/ -name SML\* mv /var/.../Images/Small` but doesnt work

Comment: maybe something like `mv /var/.../SML*  /var/.../Images/Small/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `find /var/.../Images/ -name SML\* -exec mv {} /var/.../Images/Small/ \;`

Comment: Are you sure you need the backslash before the asterisk? I would go for `-name "SML*"`.

Comment: That's also how I generally do it. I presumed OP prefer that way and I kept it since it shouldn't change the behaviour

Comment: Thank you for instant reply. I only add `-maxdepth 1` because it tried to move same files after scan subfolders

Comment: One of the joy of find ;) Glad that it helps

Comment: Note that you can always try to add before the -exec a `-not -path "*Images/Small/*"` or something like this to "exclude" some sub paths :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
dir=/path/to/your/Images
mkdir -p "$dir/Small"

find "$dir" -name "SML*" -not -wholename "$dir/Small/*" -exec mv {} "$dir/Small/" \;
```

- Since the directory you move the files to is a subdirectory of the one you seach in, you need to exclude the files already moved there. So I added `-not -wholename "$dir/Small/*"`
- To execute a command for each found file, you need `-exec ...`. The alternative would be to pipe your find results to a `while read` loop.
- When using `-exec`, the found name can be referenced by `{}`.

See `man find` for a lot more information.